# resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found. and android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error out of no where

Tags: java, android

android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found. and android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error out of no where

i have tried changing compileSdkVersion to 28 (have 27 atm) but that just gave me more errors

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
```

Android resource linking failed
Output:  E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:373: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:373: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Anton.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha13-4662957-windows.jar\3a26e83e63ade5648a5de3c39b9c37ce\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha13-4662957-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        "package name"\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\Android_Studio\AlarmTestGithub\KeepStreak\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha13-4662957-windows Daemon #0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase your `compileSdkVersion` to 29. You are using a library that requires an up-to-date `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: Do i need to do something else also or is that all?

Comment: @AutoSky: That should be all that is needed.